# Unable to locate executable file: yarn when running a GH Action in act

Tags: cypress, github-actions, pipeline, yarnpkg

I have the following GH Action:

```
name: E2E
on: push
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
      
      - name: Install dependencies cypress
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v5
        with:
          # just perform install
          runTests: false
      
      - run: yarn lint

      - name: Run e2e tests
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v5
        with:
          # we have already installed all dependencies above
          install: false
          working-directory: e2e

      - name: Download the build folders
        if: ${{ failure() }}  # Run the step only if there was a failure
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: cypress-videos
          path: videos
```

I'm running the GH Action locally with [act](https://github.com/nektos/act) which is a tool to run actions locally and it gives me the following error:

> [E2E/test] ::error::Unable to locate executable file: yarn. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.
> [E2E/test]
> Failure - Main Install dependencies cypress